# Let current user know pending posts counts using wp_query

Tags: php, functions, wp-query

I'm working on a query to let a logged-in user know if the user has more than 5 pending posts. Here's what I ended up with:

```
// Start the query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_status'    => 'pending',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));

// Start the loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    if ( $query->found_posts >= 5 ) {
        echo '5 or more pending posts';
    } else {
        echo 'Less than 5 pending posts';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    echo 'Nothing found!';
}
```

It seems working. Is there anything missing? Is there anything to correct?

Comment: You're querying _all_ (-1) pending posts just to see if there's more than 5. That's unnecessary and can be terrible for performance. Just query for 5 and if you get 5 back then there's 5 or more,

Comment: So removing the `posts_per_page` parameter makes it better?

Comment: Removing it will default to the site setting - if you're just concerned about `<>5` then set it to `5` as Jacob suggests, or perhaps even just `1`. As he implies, in it's current state the code retrieves the complete data for every applicable post - so if a user has 300 pending posts, 300 posts and all their associated metadata will be queried from the database and into the server's memory, adding a notable overhead.

Comment: also if you really only need the post count, you probably want to set the [fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter) parameter, to only return the post IDs instead of all the post data, also for performance reasons. eg: `'fields' => 'ids'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already noted in the comments, using `"posts_per_page" => 5,` is better option than `"posts_per_page" => -1,` for your query as it will give you the information you need for your conditional check.

Limiting what is queried is also something to consider - as honk31 mentioned. Along `'fields' => 'ids'` you can also add the following lines to your query.

- `'no_found_rows' => true` - number of total rows not needed in this
  case
- `'update_post_meta_cache' => false` - meta not needed in this
  case
- `'update_post_term_cache' => false` - terms not needed in this
  case

The `$query->have_posts()` with `wp_reset_postdata();` is also a bit unnecessary as you can just use `$query->found_posts` or `->post_count` directly.

```
if ( $query->found_posts ) {
  echo $query->found_posts >= 5 ? '5 or more pending posts' : 'Less than 5 pending posts';
} else {
  echo 'Nothing found!';
}
```